# Creating a list using a nested for loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to create a list using nested for loops in python. This list needs to be composed of a number of lists, each corresponding to a value of a certain parameter and containing the results of equation for that parameter. Running my code produces an `IndexError`. This is the part of my code which is causing the problem:

```
T_1 = [[]]

for j in range(len(A_1)):
        for i in range(len(y_1)):
             T_1[j][i] = T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y_1[i]) - ((A_1[j] / (2 * k_1)) * y_1[i]**2)
```

The sequences `A_1` and `y_1` are of different size (`y_1` is a 150 long list of depth points, `A_1` is a 4 character long list of different values of the parameter `A`).

Comment: Python calls these 'lists'; an `array` is something different (containing values of just one type, see the `array` module in Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lists don't grow automatically; addressing indexes that don't exist does not work. You'd normally use `.append()` for that:

```
T_1 = []

for a in A_1:
    nested = []
    T_1.append(nested) 
    for y in y_1:
        nested.append(T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y) - (a / (2 * k_1)) * y**2))
```

Note that you don't need to create indices anymore; you can loop *directly* over `A_1` and `y_1` and use the values in the formula.

The alternative would be to create an empty structure with placeholder values; like `None`:

```
T_1 = [[None] * len(y_1) for _ in range(len(A_1))]

for i, a in enumerate(A_1):
    for j, y in enumerate(y_1):
        T_1[i][j] = T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y) - (a / (2 * k_1)) * y**2))
```

Here I used [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add an index to each loop; this lets you have your cake *and* eat it; access a value from an input sequence and its location in the sequence.

However, your nested lists can most simply be generated with a nested set of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

```
T_1 = [[T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y) - ((a / (2 * k_1)) * y**2) for i in y_1] for a in A_1]
```

Here `[expression for variable in iterable]` executes the expression on the left-hand side for each iteration of the loop. The outer loop over `A_1` generates a new list for each `a` in the loop. That new list is itself a list comprehension, looping over `y_1` and generating new values (your formula) for each element.

Note that now we no longer need to generate indices *or* use `list.append()` each loop iteration. The lists are built in-place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies everyone, I have resolved the problem and continued the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
T_1 = [[T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y_1[i]) - ((A_1[j] / (2 * k_1)) * y_1[i]**2) for j in range(len(A_1))] for i in range(len(y_1))]
```

Comment: Why use `range(len(y_1))` and `range(len(A_1))` when all you use `i` and `j` for is indexing into `y_1` and `A_1`? Why not loop directly over those sequences instead?

Comment: yeah, I gave the fast answer, copy-paste... `for x in A_1` and x instead of `A_1[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

```
T_1 = []  # outer list, all rows
for j in range(len(A_1)):
    T_1.append( [] )  # new inner list, a row
    for i in range(len(y_1)):
        # last row is T_1[-1] and you append to it
        your_value = T0_1 + ((q0_1 / k_1) * y_1[i]) - ((A_1[j] / (2 * k_1)) * y_1[i]**2)
        T_1[-1].append(your_value)
```

**Reference**

```
L = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9] ]

L[0]  -> [1, 2, 3]
L[1]  -> [4, 5, 6]
L[2]  -> [7, 8, 9]
L[-1] -> [7, 8, 9]

L[0][0] -> 1
L[1][0] -> 4
L[-1][-1] -> 9
```

You may want to do it via list comprehension.
Don't even try at this point.
Because you will make a lot of mistakes.